# Multi mouse, keyboard and monitors

Tags: usb, keyboard, multiple-monitors, mouse

I've got a USB hub with 4 ports, and I've plugged 2 usb keyboards and 2 usb mouses. They work very fine. I've set up 2 monitors too, so I was thinking about the possibility of the mouse and keyboards works independent one of another. I want 2 mouse pointers (I think each with different colors) and 2 keyboard cursors.

I think it a nice idea, but I don't know if this is possible... :(

PS: My OS is Windows7

Comment: You didn't say what OS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WunderWorks' **[Teamplayer](http://www.dicolab.com/product_teamplayerpro/)** allows multiple mice/keyboards/tablets to work together on one computer, pricing starts at $14.95 (max. 5 users, for home use)

> TeamPlayer is our simplest multi-user
>   program. It gives you multiple cursors
>   on screen. It's generic, so it works
>   with any program. Simply hook up
>   multiple mice to your computer and
>   work together, using any application,
>   also includes support for dual and
>   multiple monitor setups.

Connect extra mice and keyboards to your PC.

Add a USB hub if you don’t have enough USB ports.

Download and install the software.

Double-click the TeamPlayer icon.

Multiple mice will appear.

Use your Left Mouse Button to take control.

Have fun!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I googled and found a free [driver](http://goo.gl/xoZJ) that works for Windows